# Why pushing update to Mercure Hub with PublisherInterface throw a TransferException?

Tags: docker, symfony, mercure

I'm using Mercure Hub in a Docker container on my windows machine. I've got a Symfony application and I want to use the Mercure bundle to push messages to clients.

```
/**
 * @Route("/message", name="sendMessage", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function __invoke(PublisherInterface $publisher, Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $update = new Update('https://chat.afsy.fr/message', json_encode([
        'message' => $request->request->get('message'),
    ]));

    $publisher($update);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
}
```

When I fetch this endpoint in my client javascript (i.e. publish a message to be pushed by the hub), I've got this exception from the `HTTPClient` inside the `PublisherInterface`:

> TransportException
>
> fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
> error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate
> verify failed

When I publish a message with the Mercure Debugging Tools, everything works fine but not with my Symfony app as we can see. I wonder why? :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error before.
Simply Mercure Hub requires a valid SSL Certificate in order to work, and the certificate provided by Symfony CLI (`> symfony serve`) isn't a valid one!

You can:

- Add a valid SSL certificate to your project.
- Or if it's a Symfony 4 project you can install Symfony web server
  `composer require symfony/web-server-bundle` and use `php bin/console server:run` to start the server on HTTP instead of HTTPS.
- You can also install apache-pack using `composer required apache-pack` and set a Virtual host one your machine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer :) It's a Symfony 5 project, does that mean I can't use Symfony Local Web Server for development ? Or can solutions 1 and 3 be applied with that environment ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my Symfony 4 project. And I've done solution 2. But it did not resolve the problem. I have a similar exception now, it says:  `fopen(): Unable to locate certificate CN`

Comment: @yavuz16dev when you run the project with `server:run` , does it connect to `http` or `https` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default options of the Symfony HTTP Client for the dev environment:

```
# config/packages/dev/framework.yaml
framework:

  ...

  http_client:
      default_options:
          verify_peer: false
```